# How do javascript functions have properties in them?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
function myFunc(){
    console.log(myFunc.message);
}
myFunc.message = "Hi John";

myFunc();
```

Executing the above results in -

```
Answer: 'Hi John'
```

How is the function `myFunc` have the property `message` on it? `typeof myFunc` results in "function" and `console.log(myFunc)` displays the function content (without the property `message` on it).

How does the above work? Is a function in JavaScript internally an object?

Note - I am aware that functions have other parameters like prototype and length on them. But I am not sure how these are implemented as well.

Additional query -
Since `console.log(myFunc)` does not show the object properties, how do I list all the properties of a function object?

Comment: Yes, JS functions are objects, and as such can have arbitrary properties (not parameters) attached to them.

Comment: Your tag ([tag:javascript-objects]) already answers it.

Comment: The wording in the title of this question does not read correctly. Can you rephrase it correctly in English so it makes sense?! ;-)

Comment: @JGFMK I fixed it, but it was understandable despite the error.

Comment: I think you are confusing the fact that for the syntax, a.b , b is a property - not a parameter of a. Then using incorrect wording still to describe your problem. Nearly everything in Javascript can be represented in object notation.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Am a bit confused as to why my edit was accepted and then reverted immediately? Effectively quashing my edit suggestion. I'm not really objecting just puzzled and genuinely curious. Is there some policy against editing a title?

Comment: @ChrisM The only edit I made to your correction is just that I removed the correction "parameters/properties", because even if it's the correct terminology I would avoid changing that as it may be part of OP's misunderstanding. Once I did that I just added some formatting, but most of your edits carried on in the current version.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Okay, thanks for explaining (I did notice that my minor grammar fixes was kept, but that was actually an afterthought to editing the title). Anyway, no worries I can see your reasoning.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant to ask about the properties (not parameters) on javascript functions. I have edited the title now and added an additional query.

Answer (score 5):

> How does the above work? Is function in javascript internally an object?

Yes

```js
function example() {};

console.log(example instanceof Object);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yep, [they are objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

See in particular:

> Every JavaScript function is actually a Function object. This can be seen with the code `(function(){}).constructor === Function` which returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript functions are [first class objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions). This is evidenced by the fact you can assign a function to a variable, pass it as an argument, add properties to it, add it as a property or member of an array etc etc. Sky is the limit.

```js
var myFunction = function(passedFunction){
        passedFunction();
        console.log(myFunction.message);
   };
  
let functionsArray = [myFunction, function() {
       myFunction.message = "Hello World";
}];
  
functionsArray[0](functionsArray[1]);
```

The above outputs "Hello World"

Part of the reason this can seem weird may be in the way functions can be declared. In order to behave a bit like C (but not really) or other languages where a function is in some manner defined prior to the execution of the code proper, the naked 'function' statement 'hoists' the function declaration. So where you use this syntax:

```
myFunction();
function myFunction(){ 
    console.log("Hello world");
}
```

What is actually happening is that your function declaration is being 'hoisted' to act as if it was this:

```
let myFunction = function(){ 
    console.log("Hello world");
}

myFunction();
```

These two code snippets above are fundamentally equivalent in JavaScript. (N.b. `var` declarations are also hoisted but `let` and `const` are not)

MDN [has more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) about the function declaration and function hoisting.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions), definition of function is:

> In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object. What distinguishes them from other objects is that functions can be called. In brief, they are Function objects.

So here by doing `myFunc.message` you are adding an additional property to `myFunc` function( or object) and then it is accessible inside function like other objects.